how to replace ** in excel 365 without deleting other text
how to replace **  in excel 365 without deleting other text. I have tried ~** but that did not work and it deleted the entire line. I cannot find a solution. Thanks!

Please show some sample in your post. That might help us. not necessarily you have to use a tilde but may be you need not sure. posting some sample screenshot, will help users to identify the issues and post suggestions/solutions for you!

~*~* maybe? I believe the tilde only escapes one *

You can use SUBSTITUTE function. It does not treat * as a special character.

I agree with MGonet, the substitute function maybe helpful, =SUBSTITUTE(Text,"**",New text)

Thanks - I could not get this to work. I am a full-on newbie when it comes to formulas. I will just replace these by hand. I just need patience! Appreciate the suggestions!
